# how do i add a wildcard to a file path in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Im currently writing a spock test and need to add a wild card to a file path.
the script should look into the subjects folder and into all the subfolders to find the advanced folder and look for exam.txt, however, i keep receiving an error saying FileNotFound.

I believe the code is correct as it can parse files fine but the wildcard bit throws the exception.

```
new File("School/Exams/Questions/Subjects/**/Advanced")
 if(it.name.matches("questions.txt"){
   print it
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java File class does not support wildcards which is why you are seeing the FileNotFoundException. The File class is trying to find a file with asterisk characters in the path name.

I think the groovy [AntBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/ant-builder.html) might be your friend here. Given the following groovy code:

```
new AntBuilder().fileScanner {
  fileset(dir: '.', includes: '**/Advanced/questions.txt')
}.each { File f -> 
  println "Found file ${f.path}"
}
```

(note the use of the 'search at any depth' double star wildcard in the includes pattern)

and the following directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── one
│   └── ten
│       └── Advanced
│           └── questions.txt
├── three
│   └── thirty
│       └── Advanced
└── two
    ├── twenty
    │   └── Advanced
    │       └── questions.txt
    └── twentyone
        └── Advanced
```

the script yields:

```
Found file one/ten/Advanced/questions.txt
Found file two/twenty/Advanced/questions.txt
```

with the paths abbreviated for readability.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [FileNameFinder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/util/FileNameFinder.html) to get list of file names:

```
new FileNameFinder()
    .getFileNames('School/Exams/Questions/Subjects/', '**/Advanced/questions.txt')
```

Comment: What is `FileNameHandler`? Where does it come from?

Comment: how would i be able to parse all of the `questions.txt` files after this?

Comment: you would do `def fileNames = new FileNameFinder()...` as above and then you would have to loop through the file names, create file objects for them and then do something like `file.text` to get the content.